# How to generate RGB image in python from bytes array?

Tags: python, android, sockets, opencv

I'm doing a client/server application. The client is an Android device, and the server is my PC which run python.
On the Android device, I took the preview of the camera and then convert it to an array of byte in this way (using cameraX with the analyze use case):

```
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy?, rotationDegrees: Int) {

    val buffer = image?.planes?.get(0)?.buffer
    // Extract image data from callback object
    val data = buffer?.toByteArray()
    // Convert the data into an array of pixel values
    // I commented this line, but I can use pixel value if you think is better
    //val pixels = data?.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
    Sender(mContext, mBufferedOutputStrem, mBufferedReader).execute(data)

}
private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
    val data = ByteArray(remaining())
    get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
    return data // Return the byte array
}
```

Then, with my Sender class, I send to my server the array of byte containing the image.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: ByteArray): String {
    return try {

        mBufferedOutputStream.write(p0[0])
        mBufferedOutputStream.flush()
        ..........
```

On my python server, I read the buffer with this line:

```
buf = conn.recv(4096)
```

So, buf is the array of byte. How can I convert it to an image and save it to disk? I'd also like to display the image first, with openCv.
How can I achieve this?
ps. Instead of conn.recv(4096), should I pass another value instead of 4096? If the image is less then 4096 bytes, could I encounter in any problem?

Comment: It is already unclear what kind of image you have on sender side. So start with that please. And the receiver should know what is in the received bytes. So to know what to do with it.

Comment: Why dont you send something that is a file? In that way the receiver does not have to know what is in the bytes and can just save the received bytes to file. Cant you convert to jpg before sending?

Comment: About the 4096. Probably the sender sends more bytes than that. But no problem. You should make a loop where you every time try to read 4096 bytes untit all received.

Comment: I discovered that I need to read all the three planes, not only the one in position zero.
Then with YuvImage in android, I succesfully converted the image to jpeg and to an array of byte.

Answer (score 1):

Solution code:

```
val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1280 * 720 * 2)
        val yBuffer = image?.planes?.get(0)?.buffer // Y
        val uBuffer = image?.planes?.get(1)?.buffer // U
        val vBuffer = image?.planes?.get(2)?.buffer // V

        buffer.put(yBuffer!!)
        buffer.put(vBuffer!!)
        buffer.put(uBuffer!!)

        val data = buffer.toByteArray()

        val yuvImage = YuvImage(
            buffer.array(),
            ImageFormat.NV21, image.width, image.height, null
        )

        val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(
            Rect(
                0, 0,
                image.width, image.height
            ), 50, out
        )
        val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
        val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
        Sender(mContext, mBufferedOutputStrem, mBufferedReader).execute(imageBytes)
    }

}
private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
    val data = ByteArray(remaining())
    get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
    return data // Return the byte array
}
```